# Selector targets overly obtuse - recommendations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This presumably simple task resulted in much more scripting logic than I thought would be necessary.

**Goal:** when the user clicks a button inside one of the divs, it affects said div.

**Issues:** I did not wish to have my function target specific elements in my DOM. (ex. targeting `<a>` by ID). Also, because my function is traversing the DOM and being called in multiple instances, I had to use `$(this)` format so as not to be specific to one ID.

Anyways, here is my code:

```
$(".button").toggle(function(){
    $(this).parent().children(".innerBox").fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $(this).parent().children(".innerBox").fadeOut();
});
```

It works fine. However, can someone with a little more jQuery savvy please let me how I could execute this function in the future, without having to parse through siblings and making it more convoluted than need be?

Comment: You could simplify it some by doing: `$(this).siblings(".innerBox")...`

Comment: You could just use `.toggleClass('on') / .toggleClass('off')` and add `transitions` to your CSS for the fade effect.

Comment: @Kevin Boucher That wouldn't decrease the amount of code at all, but I see what you were thinking. The amount of code I'm writing doesn't need to be truncated by a CMS or something of the sort. I merely wanted a "better way of doing this".

Comment: @JustinWard, probably something like I answered is what you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly cache the lookups, abusing of the scopes.

```
$(".button").each(function(){
  var $btn = $(this);
  var $box = $btn.parent().children(".innerBox");
  $btn.toggle(function(){
    $box.fadeIn();
  }, function(){
    $box.fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Using [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) instead of `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`.

```
$(".button").each(function(){
  var $btn = $(this);
  var $box = $btn.parent().children(".innerBox");
  $btn.click(function(){
    $box.fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

And last but not least, [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

```
$(".button").each(function(){
  var $btn = $(this);
  var $box = $btn.siblings(".innerBox");
  $btn.click(function(){
    $box.fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. .fadeToggle is nice! Good call. I too was creating variables, as I thought it might make things simpler, but it becomes a bit too confusing if others are intended to make sense of the code. Personal preferences, I guess. It's for that same reason I'm not a big fan of SASS (CSS) either.

Comment: @JustinWard, be advised, jQuery is a monster that you can't use without caching

Comment: Haha. Yeah, a bit of an oxymoron, eh? Using JQuery but not being a fan of variables...I just meant, I usually don't like creating even *more* variables.

Answer (score 1):

My only alteration would be

```
$(this).parent().children(".innerBox")
```

to instead

```
$(this).siblings(".innerBox")
```

see here: http://jsbin.com/azamot/1/edit

Comment: Haha! a selector called 'siblings'? It can't be that simple can it? Ohh. JQuery, you've done it again - making things as blatantly simple as a slap across the face.
Thanks, ceepee!